# Images all of the sudden on website give 403 errors and won't be loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, plesk, shared-hosting

I have a website that has some product category pages that serve images within a "Item Template" within a "Data List". Image is grabbed as shown:

```
<a href='<%#"/ProductPage.aspx?item="+Eval("Id")+"&cat="+Eval("Cat") %>'</a>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" class="imageViewer" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl='<%#"../Handlers/getImage.ashx?Id="+Eval("PhotoId") %>' />
</a>
```

This in turn calls the getImage.ashx handler which looks as so:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    Int32 my_Id;
    if (context.Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
    {
        my_Id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
        context.Response.ContentType = context.Request.QueryString["Type"];
        Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(my_Id);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }
    }
}

public Stream ShowEmpImage(int my_Id)
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    try {          
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetImageHandler]", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", my_Id);
        connection.Open();
        object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        connection.Close();
        return new MemoryStream();
    }
}
```

This has always worked just fine as I store the images in the database. Now all of the sudden as of late last night, the images are intermittently giving 403 errors. Link to my site and page in question: https://moneta.ggiww.com/ProductCategories?cat=Special%20Order

I have not changes any permissions or did anything different to this site. It is on Interserver Shared Hosting plan for asp.net sites. All other sites are doing the same thing. If you reload the page and click around, the images change on which ones load or not. I am at a loss on why this is all the sudden happening. I am up for all suggestions; I'll even recreate the handler if I have too. (though it always worked before as I said, this all the sudden started happening)

Forgot to mention that these sites work fine in my local environment when debugging.

Per the first comment, I tried changed to an absolute URL but still have the problems:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" class="imageViewer" runat="server" 
ImageUrl='<%#"https://moneta.ggiww.com/Handlers/getImage.ashx? 
Id="+Eval("PhotoId") %>' />
```

Comment: try using absolute paths instead of relative with "../" inside

Comment: Updated question with that absolute path. Did not help when it was published on the server